# Proof of equation of ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

The ellipse can be defined as a conic section with eccentricity lesser than unity.  How can you derive the equation of the ellipse using this definition? 
I can't find proof of the formula using this definition alone.

Comment: With the help of [Dandelin Spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandelin_spheres), the *section-of-a-cone* definition easily gives rise to the *sum-of-distances-from-two-points-is-a-constant* definition.